# Problema al implementar el salto de un personaje

Tags: python

quería implementar en un pequeño juego una función que hiciera que el personaje saltarse, cambiando sus coordenadas x e y. He probado este código pero no funciona.

```
jump=False
if pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_SPACE) and jump!=True:
        jump = True
        localY = y
        while y<=localY+5:
            y+=1
        while y>=localY:
            y-=1
```

Comment: ¿Podrías comentar el error?, o ¿decirnos cómo se comporta el salto en caso de que se produzca? Si no sabemos como se comporta el salto no podemos ayudarte, por otro lado, ¿este código es el código completo? Si no es así, sube el código completo en cuanto al salto, ya que no sabemos si ese `if`está encapsulado en un `for` o simplemente está así. Si este es el código completo no me extraña que no te funcione, pero quiero saber qué error te da o cómo se comporta el personaje para confirmar mi teoría ( que para empezar si yo spameo el espacio el personaje salta más hasta que pare de spamear)

Comment: Los bucles `while` que has escrito se ejecutarán al completo cuando se pulse el botón de salto, y durante ese tiempo el "bucle de eventos" del framework no se está ejecutando. Por tanto tus cambios en la coordenada `y` no se traducen en nada visible en la pantalla, porque la rutina de repintado no se está ejecutando. Para cuando salgas de esos bucles y el personaje se repinte, no se verá nada tampoco porque la `y` habrá recuperado su valor original.